# Añadir contenido a un modelo de YOLOv5

Tags: python, yolo

Tengo una duda acerca del funcionamiento del train de yolo:

Parto desde cero con un dataset de imágenes etiquetadas. Estas imágenes tienen un tamaño de 3840 de ancho. Cuando ejecuto el train el campo `--img` le tengo que poner el tamaño que tiene la imagen o vale poner uno menor. Luego el weight inicial que pongo, entiendo que si voy al m o l generará mejor resultado que el n o s.

Salvando estas dudas, termina el entrenamiento y se genera una carpeta *run\exp_* con los resultados, entre ellos el weight best y last. Entiendo que el best es el mejor de las iteraciones y el last la última.

Ese modelo me funciona bastante bien, pero quiero añadir más imágenes al modelo y ahí es donde me surge la duda:

Por ejemplo el primer dataset tenía 1000 imágenes y fue entrenado y generado los archivos *.pt*. Ahora quiero añadir otras 2000 imágenes al modelo:

¿Debo hacer un train desde 0 con las 3000 imágenes o es posible hacer el train de las 2000 nuevas pasando el archivo *best.pt* al campo `--weights` del *train.py*?

Me gustaría resolver la duda de si cada iteración de train tiene que ser desde cero o se puede partir de la iteración anterior.

Comment: Hola. El añadir 2000 las nuevas imágenes usando el archivo de pesos anterior puede causar que la red olvide las primeras 1000 imágenes. Otra alternativa es usar el archivo de pesos anterior y entrenarlo con las 3000 imágenes usando una cantidad de iteraciones menor que la inicial. Eso debería funcionar, pero el sistema probablemente va a funcionar un poco mejor con las primeras 1000 imágenes que con las últimas 2000, aunque creo que esto último es mejor que entrenarlo usando sólo las últimas 2000 imagenes y los pesos preexistentes (todo esto es mi opinión).